Why Does a Function using Timsort to Find the Majority Element Out of Two Elements Run Faster Than a Version of the Function That Runs in Linear Time?
Here are the two functions and a sample input in Python 3.11:
import timeit

# Time Complexity: O(n log n)
def majority_element_A(nums):
    nums.sort()
    return nums[len(nums) // 2]

# Time Complexity: O(n)
# Moore's Voting Algorithm
def majority_element_B(nums):
    candidate = nums[0]
    count = 0

    for n in nums:
        if count == 0:
            candidate = n
        count += 1 if candidate == n else -1

    return candidate

# sample input
nums = [2] * 1000 + [1] * 999

I then use Timeit to compare the two functions via:
print(min(timeit.repeat(lambda: majority_element_A(nums))))
print(min(timeit.repeat(lambda: majority_element_B(nums))))

After running these two functions through Timeit using various lengths of nums, I see that the O(n logn) version of the function consistently runs faster than the O(n) version. Why is this?

Your nums is not a very chalenging sample for checking an algorithm like majority_element_A that mainly does sorting. Did you try with random numbers ? And bigger arrays ?

I did try longer variations such as: nums = [2] * 10000 + [1] * 9999 and had the same results. I did not, however, create a random nums.

I suggested random numbers because [2] * 10000 + [1] * 9999 (or similar) is extermly well ordered. In order to evaluate a sorting algorithm you need to include at least some inputs with much less order to begin with.

For the example input pattern  (first half zero, second half one), the native sort algorithm runs in O(n). As indicated above you really need to work with non-trivial inputs.

Also, your test is broken, because the first time majority_element_A runs, nums will be sorted, which makes any next calls of majority_element_A and majority_element_B superfluous: they get an already sorted list.

Thank you @wohlstad and @trincot. I especially see where I went wrong with sorting nums with majority_element_A and then using the sorted nums as the argument to majority_element_B. However, when I use the same elements under a different list, or if I do not sort the array in place in majority_element_A, but create a new list, I get similar results. I understand now the native sort will run in O(n) since the list is mostly sorted, but majority_element_A still runs much faster. I will try with random arrays.

Even with random lists, and avoiding to sort the already sorted list (be aware that this also happens within a timeit.repeat) you'll still have the overhead of a Python-encoded loop, while sort can benefit from Python compiled into C.

@trincot: thank you so much. Your comments were very helpful.
